# Header/main files in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, header-files

I am reading about iOS programming and I bought the Programming iOS 4 book. There is a introductory part where among several things "Files" is mentioned.

I don't understand how the source files is put together. You have a header file with function declarations, then you have a corresponding file with the function definitions.

Let say you have a Car.h and Car.m & Person.h and Person.m.

Now, if you want to use the Car in the Person class you would import only the Car.h file. How  is this sufficient? I don't understand the sequence it put together and builds a program. (Not thinking about the technical stuff, just h/m files.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The `.h` or "header file" contains the interface.
- The `.m` or "implementation file" contains the implementation.

Each implementation file is also called a "compilation unit" because the compiler compiles each one separately. Within each compilation unit, the compiler needs to know about types and methods. All it needs to know about a class to create the right code is information about the methods it implements.

So let's imagine you have these files:

`Car.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
- (void)drive;
@end
```

`Car.m`

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car

- (void)drive {
    NSLog(@"I'm driving!");
}

@end
```

`Person.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Car;

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Car *car;

- (void)start;

@end
```

`Person.m`

```
#import "Person.h"
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize car;

- (void)start {
    [car drive];
}

@end
```

Now when the compiler does its business, it compiles both `Car.m` and `Person.m` into `Car.o` and `Person.o` respectively. [These then get linked into the final binary, but that's beyond the scope of this question for now].

When it compiles `Person.m`, the compiler doesn't need to know how `- (void)drive` of `Car` is implemented, but it does need to know that it exists, that it is a method that takes no arguments and returns nothing. It doesn't care about the implementation, just that it *exists*. So you just need to `#import` the header file of `Car` to tell the compiler about the methods that exist on `Car`. The compiler knows that the implementation exists, because you've told it so, and then later on the linker will do it's business to correctly wire up the method call to the correct implementation. How the linker actually does that is a huge topic and I encourage you to go and read about it separately if you don't already understand it.

Note that it's the same for all of the standard `NS` classes that you use such as `NSObject`, `NSString`, etc. You just need to `#import` `Foundation.h` from the `Foundation` framework which tells the compiler about what these classes are and what methods are defined on them.

Comment: Thank you, is header/implementation files something like interfaces and implementing classes in Java?

Comment: interfaces are related but different.  They are called protocol in objc, but in the same way the header provides a contract of methods to be implemented.

Comment: Exactly what @borrrden says. I would say if you're coming from Java, then you should have a read about the Objective-C language and try not to immediately think you know what it means by "interface", etc. Some words have slightly different meanings between Java and Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an executable from a set of source code files is a two stage process.

Firstly, all of the `.m` files are individually compiled with the Objective-C compiler.  This turns each one into a `.o` file which is an object code file.  However, if the code in a `.m` file refers to things that are defined in other `.m` files, the compiler does not know about these so it just leaves unresolved references in the .o file.

The second stage is called linking.  This takes all the `.o` files and combines them into an executable.  When the linker finds unresolved references in one `.o` file, it checks all the others to resolve the reference.

Header files allow the compiler to have some information from outside the particular `.m` file it is currently compiling.  So if you have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` they are conventionally defined in files `Foo.m` and `Bar.m`  In order for the compiler to know what class `Bar` looks like when it is compiling `Foo.m` we put class `Bar`s interface declaration in a header file (conventionally `Bar.h`) and import it into your `.m` file.  If you see the line

```
#import "Bar.h"
```

it is literally as if the compiler has copy-pasted the entire header file into the source code file before compiling it.

Comment: So, if Person.m import Person.h, and Person.h import Car.h does both declaration exists at the top of the compiled Person object file?

Answer (score 1):

What language have you been using until now?  Many languages do it this way including c and c++.  The m files are compiled into an actual program, and the h files provide a list of ways to interact with it.  While you can still call the methods if you interact with the objective c runtime, the compiler will not guarantee their existence unless they are in the h file.

Now, I say guarantee, but if you dont provide an implementation in the m file, the sibling to the compiler, the linker will have a fit.  It will try to make a jump into another m file based on its h file only to tragically discover that it is not there.

The benefits of splitting like this is that you can compile your source into a library and distribute it along with the h files and another application can use it without having the implementation source code.

In summary the m files compile into a lost island of bits and the h files are the map to get around it.  If something is on the map that doesnt exist then you will get lost.  If something exists but is not on the map then you will have a lot of trouble finding it.

Comment: I have mainly been doing Java.

Comment: Java and C# combine these two concepts into one file and compile that file into an intermediate file which is compiled (mostly) at runtime into executable code based on the system architecture.  The intermediate files contain both maps of functions and their implementations, but by default they can be reversed into source code if you are clever.  c and company skip the intermediate step and go straight to machine code so the map is lost.  It is a long and rather complicated explanation as to why they do it this way, but they have their reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Header files specify what messages ("methods" in other languages) can be passed to a class.  That's all the compiler needs to know to compile your code; the linker will eventually wire everything up, so to speak, using the `*.m` files.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will handle that for you.

As you stated, a header file contains just the declarations.
Its like a interface to the actual code and that is the only thing Compiler needs to know to fetch the rest.